# As a user without admin privileges, how can I make my own postgres database?

Tags: postgresql

I am working in a RedHat 5 environment. I have the psql command, but am not sure what I need to do to make a database. My admin would probably be willing to put reasonable things on the computer, but ideally I'd like to be able to manage my own little databases on the side.

Information on how to make the database, and what is necessary to do so, would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: To clarify: there is no postgres instance running (this is where looking things up is difficult). Assume I am a user on a more or less clean linux install. I do have the psql and createdb command, but I want a local instance of postgres on which to use them I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

Set up your own instance:

```
initdb -D ~/pgdata
postgres -D ~/pgdata --port=55555
```

You can tweak this a little to start automatically or in the background.  See the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/server-start.html).

Then you can connect:

```
psql -d postgres -p 55555
```

Answer (score 0):

You need create database privileges to do so. If you do:

```
psql -U postgres
```

And then:

```
create user foo with login;
create database bar owner foo;
\q
```

And finally:

```
psql -U foo bar
```

If you cannot create a database from lack of permissions, you might want to look into creating a [schema](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/ddl-schemas.html) as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to create a database is to issue the createdb command from your (bash?) prompt:

$ createdb mydatabasename

The man page for createdb should have more details.

This, of course, assumes that you have the appropriate database privileges.